# Referencing JSON payload value in Azure Data Factory for If condition

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have a Json file like so as a payload returned from an API call - which is an http dataset type in data factory.

```
{
    "count": 2,
    "name": "DatasetABC",
    "columnNames": [
        "Column_1",
        "Column_2"

    ],
    "rows": ["1234",
             "5678"

    ]

}
```

I would like to be able to use the count records returned in an If condition. Im wondering what I need to use to get the value of "count" which is 2.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your description, i suppose you could use [LookUp Activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-lookup-activity) in Azure Data Factory.

Lookup activity can retrieve a dataset from any of the Azure Data Factory-supported data sources. Use it in the following scenario:

> Dynamically determine which objects to operate on in a subsequent
>   activity, instead of hard coding the object name. Some object examples
>   are files and tables. Lookup activity reads and returns the content of
>   a configuration file or table. It also returns the result of executing
>   a query or stored procedure. The output from Lookup activity can be
>   used in a subsequent copy or transformation activity if it's a
>   singleton value. The output can be used in a ForEach activity if it's
>   an array of attributes.

For example,maybe you could access the count value by using `@{activity('MyLookupActivity').output.firstRow.count}` in the [IF activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-if-condition-activity).