# How to copy data in Azure Data Factory depending on the values?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

my problem is this:
For example, I have a table with three columns in SQL Server table1(id, number1, number2) and other table2(id,finalNumber). How can I do a conditional copy? I want to copy the bigger number of each row in the table2(finalNumber). I thought a LookUp->IfConditionally but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the example in the [IfCondition activity document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-if-condition-activity),it could be used to quote the output data from look up activities.Like `@{activity('MyLookupActivity').output.firstRow.count}`. You could refer to my previous case:[Referencing JSON payload value in Azure Data Factory for If condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54934549/referencing-json-payload-value-in-azure-data-factory-for-if-condition/54939839#54939839)

In addition,one more idea is using stored procedure.You could this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-sql-server#invoking-stored-procedure-for-sql-sink) to configure sql server stored procedure in your [sql server sink](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-sql-server#sql-server-as-sink).

[image]

Then you could copy the data from source table to the temporary table.And do the number contrast business and insert operations in the stored procedure.There are very detailed steps i did in my previous case: [Azure Data Factory mapping 2 columns in one column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51352725/azure-data-factory-mapping-2-columns-in-one-column/51354266#51354266,please) refer to it.

Any concern,let me know.